# std::sort that also keeps track of number of unique entries at each level

Tags: c++, algorithm, std

Say I have a std::vector. Say the vectors contain numbers. Let's take this std::vector

1,3,5,4,3,4,5,1,6,3

```
std::sort<std::less<int>> will sort this into
```

1,1,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,

How would I ammend sort so that at the same time it is sorting, it also computes the quantity of numbers at the same level. So say in addition to sorting, it would also compile the following dictionary [level is also int]

```
std::map<level, int>

<1, 2>
<2, 3>
<3, 2>
<4, 2>
<5, 1>
<6, 1>
```

so there are 2 1's, 3 3's, 2 4's, and so on.

The reason I [think] I need this is because I don't want to sort the vector, THEN once again, compute the number of duplicates at each level. It seems faster to do it both in one pass?

Thank you all! bjskishore123 is the closest thing to what I was asking, but all the responses educated me. Thanks again.

Comment: You can create the map separately by using std::count on the elements. or iterate over the sort results to build the map by your own. No need to complicate the sort process. The number of operations needed for the map should not be able to be reduced even if you enhance the sorting part.

Comment: It's probably not faster to do it in a single step, it's probably fastest to do two passes.

Comment: "It seems faster to do it both in one pass." You're not even *sorting* in one pass, so this is not accurate as a baseline. You can do this in O(NlogN + N), equivalent to O(NlogN), by simply single-pass scanning the sorted list, incrementing an occurrence pair vector and adding a new pair as you move to a new value in your sorted list. I would think it unlikely you will get a faster solution than that, especially since `sort()` really doesn't care how "many" of something is present; rather it cares only about the *ordering*. But you don't need a map OR a set if all you care about is the counts.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a vector,

While storing number one by one, Use **std::multiset** container

It stores internally in sorted order.

While storing each number, use a map to keep track of the number of occurrences of each number.

```
map<int, int> m;
```

Each time a number is added do

```
m[num]++;
```

So, no need of another pass to calculate the number of occurrences, although you need to iterate in map to get each occurrence count.

=============================================================================

THE FOLLOWING IS AN ALTERNATE SOLUTION WHICH IS **NOT RECOMMENDED** . 
**GIVING IT AS YOU ASKED A WAY WHICH USES STD::SORT**.

Below code makes use of comparison function to count the occurrences.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Elem
{
    int index;
    int num;
};

std::map<int, int> countMap; //Count map
std::map<int, bool> visitedMap;
bool compare(Elem a, Elem b)
{
    if(visitedMap[a.index] == false)
    {
        visitedMap[a.index] = true;
        countMap[a.num]++;
    }
    if(visitedMap[b.index] == false)
    {
        visitedMap[b.index] = true;
        countMap[b.num]++;
    }
    return a.num < b.num;
}

int main()
{
    vector<Elem> v;
    Elem e[5] = {{0, 10}, {1, 20}, {2, 30}, {3, 10}, {4, 20} };
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        v.push_back(e[i]);

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare);

    for(map<int, int>::iterator it = countMap.begin(); it != countMap.end(); it++)
        cout<<"Element : "<<it->first<<" occurred "<<it->second<<" times"<<endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Element : 10 occurred 2 times
Element : 20 occurred 2 times
Element : 30 occurred 1 times
```

Comment: Is the complexity of your alghorithm O(n*logn²)

Comment: @Ian: Which one? first or second?

Comment: The sorting + map insertion. You will traverse the vector n * log(n) times to sort. In each time you access the vector, it's done a map insertion, that's O(logn). I think the resulting complexity is O(n * logn²)

Comment: Is it not O(n log n) + O(log n)

Comment: I don't think so. The map insertion is being done in each access to the vector while ordering, wich is done n * logn times - O(nlogn) * O(logn) = O(nlogn²). O(n log n) + O(log n) would be the case if the vector was ordered and the map populated in different loops. But as you stated, it's really not recommended to use your implementation. It's theorectically more inneficient than: ordering + counting: O(n log n) + O(n)).

Comment: Map insertion happens only once per occurrence of element. Visited map is being checked before doing any count map updation. So map doesn't get updated for each vector access.

Comment: Are you not counting the access to visitedMap ? It's also O(logn). You do 3 map access in the worst case....

Comment: oh yes. we can replace visited map with a simple bool array.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @bjskishore123, you can use a map to guarantee the correct order of your set. As a bonus, you will have an optimized strucutre to search (the map, of course).

Inserting/searching in a map takes O(log(n)) time, while traversing the vector is O(n). So, the alghorithm is O(n*log(n)). Wich is the same complexity as any sort algorithm that needs to compare elements: merge sort or quick sort, for example.

Here is a sample code for you:

```
int tmp[] = {5,5,5,5,5,5,2,2,2,2,7,7,7,7,1,1,1,1,6,6,6,2,2,2,8,8,8,5,5};
std::vector<int> values(tmp, tmp + sizeof(tmp) / sizeof(tmp[0]));
std::map<int, int> map_values;
for_each(values.begin(), values.end(), [&](int value)
{
    map_values[value]++;
});

for(std::map<int, int>::iterator it = map_values.begin();  it != map_values.end(); it++)
{
    std::cout << it->first << ": " << it->second << "times";
}
```

Output:

```
1: 4times
2: 7times
5: 8times
6: 3times
7: 4times
8: 3times
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in one pass. Let's say you provide your own custom `comparator` for sorting which somehow tries to count the duplicates.

However the only thing you can capture in the sorter **is the value(*maybe reference but doesn't matter*)** of **the current two elements being compared**. You have no other information because `std::sort` doesn't pass any thing else to the sorter.

Now the way `std::sort` works it will keep swapping elements until they reach the proper location in the sorted vector. That means a **single member can be sent to the sorter multiple times** making it impossible to count exactly. **You can count how many times a certain element and all others value equal to it have been moved** but not exactly how many of them are in there.

Comment: Yes, using std::sort it's probably not possible.

Comment: @Ian: It is possible but lot of unnecessary storage and inefficient algo has to be used like my 2nd solution.

Comment: @bjskishore123 Yes of course. I was not trying to say it is impossible completely. I was just trying to say that it is not really "a one pass" where you **count as you sort**. Of course it is possible if you go the extra mile.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lots of duplicates, the fastest way to accomplish this task is probably to first count duplicates using a hash map, which is `O(n)`, and then to sort the map, which is `O(m log m)` where `m` is the number of unique values.

Something like this (in c++11):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> uniqsort(const std::vector<int>& v) {
  std::unordered_map<int, int> count;
  for (auto& val : v) ++count[val];
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> result(count.begin(), count.end());
  std::sort(result.begin(), result.end());
  return result;
}
```

There are lots of variations on the theme, depending on what you need, precisely. For example, perhaps you don't even need the result to be sorted; maybe it's enough to just have the count map. Or maybe you would prefer the result to be a sorted map from int to int, in which case you could just build a regular `std::map`, instead. (That would be `O(n log m)`.) Or maybe you know something about the values which make them faster to sort (like the fact that they are small integers in a known range.) And so on.

Comment: Thank you all for your generous help!